# How to read this XPath code

Tags: xml, xpath

im learning XPath and I found an example which I dont really understand. Can someone "translate" it?

Matching xpath:

```
//span[@class='username']/../../..//span[@class='commentDate']
```

relative xpath:

```
/../../..//span[@class='commentDate']
```

Does it mean that: it selects all "class" elemets that have an attribute "commentDate" between the element/attribute (class/username) and element/attribute (class/commentDate)?

I dont really udnerstand this part `/../../..`

Comment: The relative path does not have a leading `/`.  What would `../../..` mean as part of a file path?  And also, BTW, that is a very "brittle" path.  It explicitly depends on the overall structure of the XML and will break if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get you to understand that `xpath` of yours and `xpath` terminologies in general.

`//span[@class='username']/../../..//span[@class='commentDate']`

There are two types of `xpath`: `Relative` and `Absolute`. As the name suggests, `Relative` `xpath` finds a node relative to an another node (generally the short ones starting with `.//`) and `Absolute` `xpath` generally identifies a node from its corresponding `root` node (generally the long ones starting with `html/body/..../....`).

A single `/` at start means starting the process from root and a `//` at start means finding all nodes that match your `xpath` which can be anywhere in your `DOM`.

Coming to your `xpath`, it starts with `//` which means (in literal english) find me all the `span` whose `class` is `username`. A single slash after an element means its `child`. However, a double `..` means `parent` of that node. So find me that `span` with `class=username` and get me its `parent`. Continuing your xpath, its says find its `parent`, its `parent`, its `parent` and then find a `span` in the `child`'s of last `parent` whose `class` is `commentDate`. This `child` can be `child` or `grandchild` or `great-grandchild` and so on.

Hope this paints a picture of some sort.

Comment: Definitely! Thank you for the comprehensive explanation! :)

Comment: If the answer addresses your question or solves it, please accept the answer. Thanks.